# Make native submit() event return a value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to have a form's submit() action return data into the lexical scope of where it was called? I want something like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("div").click(function() {
    var submitReturn = $("form").submit();
    // do stuff with submitReturn
    ...
    // end do stuff with submitReturn
  }):

  $("form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // do stuff
    ...
    // end do stuff

    return someObj;
  });
});
```

This doesn't work. The actual `submit(function)` registration just registers the function as a callback in the event's chain, it doesn't take over the whole thing.

I suppose I could just do this by having the `.click` event use `$.post()` instead of `$('form').submit()`, which is an entirely satisfactory option in the real-world use case, but now I'm curious if what I want can be done.

Answer (score 2):

You could split it out into another function:

```
$(function() {
  function submit() {
    // do stuff
    ...
    // end do stuff

    return someObj;
  }

  $("div").click(function() {
    var submitReturn = submit();
    // do stuff with submitReturn
    ...
    // end do stuff with submitReturn
    // Do you call $("form").submit() here anyways? Depends on the situation.
  }):

  $("form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    submit();
  });
});
```

(Assuming there’s one form.) If it's an asynchronous thing, though, you'll need to pass a callback instead.